# Combing data from multiple workbooks into a single master workbook using power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am currently proposing a solution regarding report governance. The aim is to store information of all the reports and fields we currently use in one master workbook. To do this the plan is to save a copy of each report in a folder and then have a master workbook pull the data from workbooks in this folder, taking just the headings as they will indicate the fields used . Currently I am at the proof of concept stage for small example workbooks. But I am struggling to get only the headers of each report to show on the master workbook as a row each. Any help ? :)

Currently completely lost. Ideally I want each row to correspond to a workbook saved in the selected folder with the first cell being the filename and then the subsequent cells in the row being the column headers of the reports

Comment: did this solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Below in powerquery would read in the contents of all the files in a directory, and just return the values on the first row of data, which presumably has your column headers on them. It includes the name of the tabs and file

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GetFileData", "Data2", each Table.FirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]),1)),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom1"[Data2], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Data2", List,List),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Content", "Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```